# Serial port becomes unresponsive on Ubuntu 20.04, but works on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, serial-port, usb, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04

I wrote a C++ program to continuously read data from a device, via serial over USB. The program works flawlessly in [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver). I have an identical system running [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa) and the same program does not work properly. It will read a few KB from the serial port, but then no more data is detected by read().

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int receive_data(int fd, unsigned char read_buf[], int num_requested_bytes)
{
    int total_received_bytes = 0;
    int num_received_bytes = 0;

    // Continue reading the serial port until the number of requested bytes have been read
    while (total_received_bytes < num_requested_bytes)
    {
        num_received_bytes = read(fd, read_buf + total_received_bytes,
                                  num_requested_bytes - total_received_bytes);
        if (num_received_bytes < 0)
        {
            if (errno == EAGAIN)
            {
                num_received_bytes = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Encountered error during read(): " << errno << std::endl;
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
        total_received_bytes += num_received_bytes;

        if (total_received_bytes >= num_requested_bytes)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return total_received_bytes;
}

int main()
{
    // Open serial port
    int fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
    int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    //fcntl(fd, F_SETFL,  flags | O_ASYNC); // <------------------- SEE NOTE

    // Read in existing settings, and handle any error
    struct termios tty;
    if(tcgetattr(fd, &tty) != 0)
    {
        close(fd);
        printf("Error %i from tcgetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Set flags
    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;

    // Raw input mode
    cfmakeraw(&tty);

    // Save tty settings, also checking for error
    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
        close(fd);
        printf("Error %i from tcsetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    // Attempt to read from port
    int received_bytes;
    unsigned char read_buf[1024];
    while (true)
    {
        received_bytes = receive_data(fd, read_buf, 1024);
        std::cout << "Received " << received_bytes << " bytes. First 2 numbers in frame: "
                  << ((unsigned int) (read_buf[1] << 8 | read_buf[0])) << ", "
                  << ((unsigned int) (read_buf[3] << 8 | read_buf[2])) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here is example output from the program in Ubuntu 20.04. After 0-3 frames, I no longer receive any data and the program endlessly loops on my read() call.

On Ubuntu 18.04, the program will continue endlessly.

```
$ ./main
Received 1024 bytes. First 2 numbers in frame: 65535, 2046
Received 1024 bytes. First 2 numbers in frame: 2046, 3338
Received 1024 bytes. First 2 numbers in frame: 2045, 2046
```

***See note***:

If I enable the O_ASYNC flag, the program will exit on the first `read()` with `I/O Possible` printed in the terminal. If I then comment out the line and recompile, the program runs and fetches frames continuously as expected.

What could be causing this?

Comment: You over-program for nonblocking I/O, yet your program merely wastes CPU cycles looping for data.  How have you verified that these two systems are *"identical"*?  Have you tested data reception (from your mystery device) using a standard utility, e.g. minicom?  BTW in **receive_data()**, the `if () break` is a redundant test with the `while ()` loop.

Comment: Using your program as posted, I'm *unable* to replicate any failure as you reported using Lubuntu 20.04.  Program hogs the CPU, and displays messages for as many minutes as I let the program run.  Problem cannot be duplicated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The systems are as identical as two Latte Panda Alphas could be. I looked into the communications with minicom and believe there is an issue with the firmware on the device. I got a new version, hopefully that fixes the issues.